# Get VMWare to use integrated Ubuntu menu

Tags: vmware, menu

In VMWare Player 7.1.0 on Ubuntu 15.04, the menu is shown below the title bar and looks rather out of place.

[image: VMWare Player menu bar]

Is there a way to get VMWare to integrate the menu the title bar, using the same sort of menu system as other Ubuntu applications?